# How to Create Access Token in Magento 2 integration

Tags: magento-2.1, access, token

I have created one new Integration and gave access but i did n't get Access token is there i doing anything wrong let me help to resolve this issue

Comment: Yes admin Access token.I am trying to upload the bulk product from script so i am gonna use SOAP API for that purpose i need that Access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "Activate" an Integration to get an Access Token in the admin interface. After you create a new Integration and Save it, in the list of Integrations you should see an "activate" link. Clicking this you will be asked to approve the permissions, then you will get a screen with the tokens.

To get the tokens again later, "Edit" on that Integration (once it's Active) and you should see, in the "Integration Info" tab, the "Integration Details" section below. It will have the Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, 
and the now-populated Access Token and Access Secret.

Comment: After clicking activate button it shown the permission given for that user and after that i clicked allow it shown like this "Please setup or sign in into your 3rd party account to complete setup of this integration." what i need to integrate?

Comment: I think that's just saying "now that you have the access tokens, which you probably created because you want a 3rd party service to use the Magento APIs - go to that 3rd party service now, and enter them"

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of getting access token in magento 2.

1. we create it via magento 2 backend manually
2. build a magento integration extension to create it programatically

we made a very detail blog to explain how it works here:

[how to create magento 2 integration manually and programatically](https://www.beehexa.com/devdocs/how-to-create-an-integration-in-magento-2/)

There are some pictures you can take a look to review the process:

#### 1. Magento 2 Integration Menu

[image: Step 1: Integration Menu]

#### 2. Magento 2 New Integration Form

[image: Step 2: Integration Form]

#### 3. Granting APIs Access for Your Integration

[image: Step 3: This is important for you; granting access for API]

#### 4. Activating Your Integration

[image: Step 4: Activating to generate access token]

#### 5. Review & Copy The Access token to use in your App.

[image: Step 5: Your Access Token Detail]

The process of creating access token programmatically is a little bit more complex.
Please check our blog above to see more detail.

Comment: how can we get access token by programaticaly?